# index rows by year in F#

Tags: f#

i am reading my data as a frame on F# as follows

```
let myannual = Frame.ReadCsv("data/annual.csv")
```

My frame consists of time series columns and a year column, and I would like to index my time series by year. I cannot do it as follows

```
 let myyears = [| for i in myannual.GetColumn<float>("yyyy").Values -> float i |] 
 let myindexedframe = myannual.IndexRows(myyears)
```

What should I do? Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: first you should produce a minimal working example of your problem - in this case you should give the structure of your `annual.csv` (maybe a few rows and the header) **then** you should say what your problem is: Is it a compiler error? Do you get the wrong values back? - as it is your question is just not answerable and that is probably why you got a downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReadCsv` method takes an optional parameter `indexCol` that can be used to specify the index column - and you also need to provide a type parameter to tell Deedle what is the type of the index:

```
let myannual = Frame.ReadCsv<int>("data/annual.csv", indexCol="yyy")
```

Your approach would work too, but you'd need to use `IndexRowsWith`, which takes a sequence of new indices (and it is better to use `int` because `float` is imprecise for years):

```
let myyears = [| for i in myannual.GetColumn<float>("yyyy").Values -> int i |] 
let myindexedframe = myannual.IndexRowsWith(myyears)
```

The `IndexRows` method takes just the name of a column (very similar to using the `indexCol` parameter when calling `ReadCsv`):

```
let myindexedframe = myannual.IndexRows<int>("yyyy")
```